# Contains is always false, because reference is not the same?

Tags: c#, wpf, generic-list

I am implementing an application, in which you have to validate if some object is in a list. This happens with `.contains` I know, but I fill up my list with an XML file, and then the object which I check if the list contains this, is newly created so the references are not the same and `.Contains` will always be false.
Someone who knows to fix this problem? This is the code:

```
if (qfs.Contains(exa.Question.File))
{
    booleansQuestionFile[i] = true;
}
```

The `if` statement is always false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132407.aspx), `Contains` uses the default equality comparer. To change the default behavior, make your class implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) or override [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You should override the [Equals method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) That way you can define when two objects are the same.

Answer (score 1):

The objects that are stored in the list should implement IEquatable. This way it does not matter that the references are different it will still compare them for equality properly.

---

Here is a [link to an article](http://en.csharp-online.net/IEquatable) that shows an example. And this [blog post](http://blog.noop.se/archive/2008/10/10/how-to-override-.equals-.gethashcode-and-implement-iequatablelttgt.aspx) goes into more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have such code instead, it will save you the need to change the class:

```
if (qfs.Exists(f => f.Question.File.Equals(exa.Question.File)))
{
    booleansQuestionFile[i] = true;
}
```